# "Not enough Space" But Installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a 172 gb Partition. Can Someone Help Me

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I have a Laptop with two disks:

1. NVMe 2 Disk with Windows Installed.
2. A second Disk with a partition for Ubuntu of 180 GB.

So I installed Ubuntu on the second disk, but encountered error no space on disk.

[image: Disk Image Analyzer From Ubuntu Low Amount of Space]

[image: Free Space on Disk (The Partition I Made for Ubuntu]

Can someone please explain what is happening and how to obtain that free space?

Output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` command:

```
{NAME        FSTYPE     SIZE MOUNTPOINT                   LABEL
loop0       squashfs 255.6M /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36     
loop1       squashfs    55M /snap/core18/1880            
loop2       squashfs  62.1M /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506 
loop3       squashfs  49.8M /snap/snap-store/467         
loop4       squashfs  29.9M /snap/snapd/8790             
loop5       squashfs  29.9M /snap/snapd/8542             
loop6       squashfs 118.9M /snap/slack/27               
loop7       squashfs  55.3M /snap/core18/1885            
sda                  953.9G                              
├─sda1                  16M                              
├─sda2      ntfs     781.3G                              NTFS 800 gbs
└─sda3      ext4     172.6G /                            
nvme0n1              238.5G                              
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs      16.1G                              Recovery
├─nvme0n1p2 vfat       100M /boot/efi                    SYSTEM
├─nvme0n1p3             16M                              
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     221.3G                              Blade 15 SSD
└─nvme0n1p5 ntfs      1000M                              Winre}
```

Output of `df` command:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8118092        0   8118092   0% /dev
tmpfs            1629252     2252   1627000   1% /run
/dev/sda3      177098612 19833896 148198940  12% /
tmpfs            8146244   101560   8044684   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8146244        0   8146244   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1         56320    56320         0 100% /snap/core18/1880
/dev/loop0        261760   261760         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
/dev/loop4         30720    30720         0 100% /snap/snapd/8790
/dev/loop3         51072    51072         0 100% /snap/snap-store/467
/dev/loop2         63616    63616         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop6        121856   121856         0 100% /snap/slack/27
/dev/loop5         30720    30720         0 100% /snap/snapd/8542
/dev/loop7         56704    56704         0 100% /snap/core18/1885
/dev/nvme0n1p2     98304    52529     45775  54% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1629248       52   1629196   1% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: I suspect you did not use all available HD space for your Ubuntu installation, or maybe selected the wrong disk or something. Could you please post the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL` so we can verify this?

Comment: Thanks For Your Response I just added an image of the command "sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL" in the description.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/49BkD.png

Comment: @Hector Medina the output of `df` may help as well. Also, please don't add screenshots but copy and paste the output in your question as a code block if possible.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text from the terminal. Copy and paste the text directly into the edit question window. Then format the pasted text as code using the { } icon.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion please find attached requested info

Answer (score 0):

As it seems that the disk on which you install has enough space, it must be the installation media that suffers from a defect.

[Check the integrity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the installation media.